# analysing a wallet on a specific contract (web3js/ethers)

Tags: web3js, transactions, ethers.js, nft, dapp-development

is it possible to obtain the transactions of an eth address on a given contract (nft)?
at the moment the os API does not allow this, or rather, I would have to iterate over all wallet transactions until I find the desired contract. is it possible to do this with ethers or web3js?